# Trouble with running cd with sudo as another user

Tags: sudo, cd-command

I want to run a command on a shell on behalf of another user. The command is as follows:

```
sudo -u USER cd /home/USER
```

I get

```
sudo: cd: command not found
```

What is the correct syntax for the command to pass to sudo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cd` is a [**shell builtin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin). You need to invoke shell for executing shell builtins:

```
sudo -u USER sh -c 'cd /home/USER'
```

OR

```
sudo -u USER bash -c 'cd /home/USER'
```

Comment: This won't really do anything useful---the shell will exit right after the `cd`. OP probably wants `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 6):

`cd` is not an external command, it is only a shell builtin, so `sudo` cannot execute it. The reason why `cd` only exists as a shell builtin is that a process cannot affect the current directory of another process; therefore a program that changes the current directory and exits immediately is useless. (Almost useless: a `cd` program would return a status that indicates whether it was successful.)

If you want to change to a directory and then run commands as another user, run a shell that does all that.

```
sudo -u SOMEUSER sh -c 'cd /path/to/directory && dosomething'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use:`sudo su - USERNAME` and then do what you need as that user. To quit just type `exit`

Comment: logging as `USERNAME` and then executing command is different that directly running command as `USERNAME`